# Passing subscription data through templates

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

sorry for my english.

The problem:

I have template "tempA" subscribe to "subs1". From tempA I create dynamically "tempB" (Blaze.render) then I have to subscribe to "sub1" again and wait for finish?

There is a way to use data from subs1 of tempA in tempB?

Thanks and sorry for my english again.

Answer (score 2):

If your `tempB` is always inside `tempA`, then you can directly query the data, because collections are a reactive data source and will update helpers and UI reactively whenever new data comes in from server to client.

If you want to show a loading message or something similar, you can pass the subscription handler to `tempB` using [`Blaze.renderWithData`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_renderwithdata) and pass data, I think. When you subscribe save a reference to subscription handler like this,

```
Template.tempA.created = function () {
    var template = this;
    template.handler = template.subscribe('subs1');
}
```

Then you can pass this reference to `tempB` using Blaze.renderWithData like this,

```
Blaze.renderWithData(Template.tempB, template.handler)
```

Then you can check whether this subscription is ready in `tempB` using subscription handler's reference stored in `Template.currentData()`.

I didn't try this and I have never used `Blaze.renderWithData` or `Blaze.render`, so I am not entirely sure if it works. Hope it helps.